# The root of a monic polynomial with algebraic coefficients.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Let α be a complex number that satisfies α<sup>3</sup> + βα<sup>2</sup> + γα + δ = 0

β, γ, and δ satisfy cubics with rational coefficients.  For example, β satisfies β<sup>3</sup> + aβ<sup>2</sup> + bβ + c = 0.  However, it is not stated that these do not satisfy polynomials of smaller degree, so their degrees are ≤ 3.

I am trying to find an upper bound for α over the rational numbers, as well as show that the minimal polynomial of α over the rationals does not have degree of precisely five.

Comment: Are you looking for any upper bound or a strict one?

Comment: I'm looking for a strict upper bound, but any upper bound would be appreciated as a nudge in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an upper bound, can you find an upper bound for $[\mathbb Q(\beta, \gamma): \mathbb Q]$? 
Observe that $[\mathbb Q(\beta): \mathbb Q] \le [\mathbb Q(\beta, \gamma):\mathbb Q(\gamma)]$, since a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ is also a polynomial over $\mathbb Q(\gamma)$.

Since you have an upper bound for $[\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma): \mathbb Q(\beta, \gamma)]$, you can obtain a bound for $[\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma): \mathbb Q]$ using the tower law. This will also be an upper bound for $[\mathbb Q(\alpha): \mathbb Q]$.

If $[\mathbb Q(\alpha): \mathbb Q] = 5$, then

$$5 \mid [\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma): \mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma): \mathbb Q(\beta, \gamma)]\cdot [\mathbb Q(\beta, \gamma) :\mathbb Q(\beta)]\cdot [\mathbb Q(\beta):\mathbb Q]$$

So since $5$ is prime, it divides one of $[\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma): \mathbb Q(\beta, \gamma)],\  [\mathbb Q(\beta, \gamma) :\mathbb Q(\beta)], \ [\mathbb Q(\beta):\mathbb Q]$. Can this occur?

Comment: It cannot!  All extensions are of degree ≤ 3.  Thank you so much!